# Admin access through a GET parameter

Tags: security, authentication

I'm working on a really simple web site. I usually do a full blown admin to edit the site, but this time I thought about editing in place (contenteditable="true").

To simplify login for the user, I'd like to just give him a password that he can type in the address bar to log him in, instead of the usual login form. So he would visit domain.com/page?p=the_password and then I would store his data in a session and give him a cookie with a session id (usual stuff) and redirect him to domain.com/page.

How safe / unsafe is this? I'm doing this in PHP, but I guess it applies to any server-side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Celada answer. The URL will be stored in the browser history or network caches/proxies, so the password can leak in this way. Also it would be trivial to login a random Internet user as someone else (Login Cross Site Request Forgery attack), by for example having a web site with an img element pointing to domain.com/page?p=the_password

You don't write about this, but once the user is logged in your scheme needs to protect against Cross Site Request Forgery (so a random page can not perform admin actions on behave of the logged-in user).

Answer (score 2):

Your login idea is unsafe: URLs for requests end up in web server logs and other places besides, so that means passwords will end up in web server logs.

Your "contentedittable" idea is probably unsafe, but in a more subtle way. It's also (again, probably) non-compliant with the HTTP specification.

`GET` requests should always be idempotent. This is because user agents (browsers, caches, etc...) are allowed to reissue the same `GET` request any number of times without user consent. One reason why a browser might do that is because the user pressed the back button and the previous page is no longer in the cache. If the request is not idempotent then issuing it a second time may have an unexpected and unwanted side effect.

It sounds like your "editing in place" feature might not always be idempotent. There are many kinds of simple edits which are in fact idempotent so I could be wrong, but as soon as you have for example the ability to add a new item to a list via this kind of interface it's not.

Non-idempotent requests should be issued through methods like `PUT`, `POST`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you misunderstood the part about contenteditable. This is not supposed to work through a GET request and is in my case independent of the login method. I was just trying to tell what I was doing, but the two are not connected.  
  
Okay, so server logs, that's unsafe, point taken. Anything else? I guess I'm not worried about someone reading my logs. If someone can, than he can do a lot of damage either way.

Comment: @duality_ if the user types the url in the address bar, a GET request is generated.

Comment: @duality_: It's true, I did misunderstand you about contenteditable. Sorry about that. But Jan has added some more good reasons why a password in a GET is unsafe. I would stay away from doing it.